# Efficient Poisson solver compatible with MPI

Tags: linux, library, c++, modeling, fortran

To solve a [Poisson equation](http://planetmath.org/poissonsequation), I am currently using code which uses the [Hypre](http://acts.nersc.gov/hypre/) library with [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). I would like to know what else is out there, and if there is some accepted standard in the industry, i.e. what do most people use?

The library must be able to work for **2D** and **3D** cases, relatively easy to incorporate into an existing code and **MPI compatible**. It should work either with **Fortran** (preferred) or **C++**/**C**.

Answer (score 0):

> [Rheolef](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Pierre.Saramito/rheolef/) is a programming environment that serves as a convenient
>   laboratory for computations involving finite element methods.
>   *Rheolef* is both a *C++ library* and a set of commands for *unix shell* programming, providing algorithms and data structures.

Among its features:

- Massively distributed memory finite element environment, based on MPI
- Poisson problems in dimension d=1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at: https://freefem.org/

I used it to solve Poisson on 2D and 3D unstructured meshes using finite elements.

They had implemented some MPI some time back:
https://doc.freefem.org/documentation/parallelization.html

The team that developed this solver is still active (researchers from JLL lab of University Paris VI).